# segmentation fault with fgets from input file in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This function uses `fgets` to input data from a file and store it in a structure. I am getting a segmentation fault and I cannot figure out why. The program won't run so I have not been able to debug. Here is the code for the function:

```
void getInventory(NodeT **ppRoot, char *pszInventoryFileName)
{
    char szInputBuffer[100];       // input buffer for reading data
    int iScanfCnt;                 // returned by sscanf
    FILE *pfileInventory;          // Stream Input for Inventory data.
    Stock *pNew = NULL;

    /* open the Inventory stream data file */
    if (pszInventoryFileName == NULL)
            exitError(ERR_MISSING_SWITCH, "-i");

    pfileInventory = fopen(pszInventoryFileName, "r");
    if (pfileInventory == NULL)
            exitError(ERR_INVENTORY_FILENAME, pszInventoryFileName);

    /* get inventory data until EOF
    ** fgets returns null when EOF is reached.
    */
    while (fgets(szInputBuffer, 100, pfileInventory) != NULL)
    {
            iScanfCnt = sscanf(szInputBuffer, "%6s %ld %lf %30[^\n]\n"
                    , pNew->szStockNumber
                    , &pNew->lStockQty
                    , &pNew->dUnitPrice
                    , pNew->szStockName);

            if (iScanfCnt < 4)
                    exitError(ERR_INVALID_INVENTORY_DATA, "\n");

            if (pNew == NULL)
                    exitError("Memory allocation error", "");

            printT(insertT(*ppRoot, *pNew));
    }
}
```

The `printT` and `insertT` functions are recursive but the program fails before it get that far. And here is the data from the input file:

```
PPF001 100 9.95 Popeil Pocket Fisherman
SBB001 300 14.95 Snuggie Brown
SBG002 400 14.95 Snuggie Green
BOM001 20 29.95 Bass-O-Matic
MCW001 70 12.45 Miracle Car Wax
TTP001 75 9.95 Topsy Turvy Planter
NHC001 300 9.95 Electric Nose Hair Clipper
SSX001 150 29.95 Secret Seal
```

Why does this code give me a segmentation fault?

Comment: BTW `nsertT(*ppRoot, *pNew)` : 1st argument type might `NodeT **`

Comment: "The code won't run so I cannot debug" -- but it *does* run, else you would not get a run-time error! Are you confusing 'running' with 'compiling' or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that although you are checking `pNew` allocation for `NULL`, you never actually *allocate* memory to it.

Add a call to `malloc` assigning to `pNew` and the memory check ahead of `sscanf` call to fix this problem:

```
while (fgets(szInputBuffer, 100, pfileInventory) != NULL)
{
        pNew = malloc(sizeof(Stock));
        if (pNew == NULL)
                exitError("Memory allocation error", "");

        iScanfCnt = sscanf(szInputBuffer, "%6s %ld %lf %30[^\n]\n"
                , pNew->szStockNumber
                , &pNew->lStockQty
                , &pNew->dUnitPrice
                , pNew->szStockName);

        if (iScanfCnt < 4)
                exitError(ERR_INVALID_INVENTORY_DATA, "\n");

        printT(insertT(*ppRoot, *pNew));
}
```